# Proof approach: A 7x7 matrix with 15 ones can allow at least three marriages

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algorithms

This is quite difficult to prove imho with regards to Hall's Marriage Algorithm  I can visualize a number of scenarios that work (i.e. put ones from the first entry to the fifteenth, or across diagonals) and they all work.  However I'm not so sure how to write it down for a generic case.  Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 0):

Minimise the number of possible marriages by reducing the number of matches i.e. number of rows or columns that have any ones.
Since any row or column can have at most 7 ones, two rows or two columns can have at most 14 ones between them. Then you have an extra one that must go in a different row or column, and this entry dictates a marriage. Then the previous row/column has six further possible exclusive matches to give a second marriage; then the initial row/column has five further possible exclusive matches to give a third marriage. So there is a minimum of 3 marriages.